# File not appearing in IOS programming

Tags: iphone, ios, image, file, projection-matrix

I am using Xcode to program a new application that is of the game sorts, and when I run it the file that I am using as a main character does not appear.  It is just a basic script, but I want it to all be right the first time.  Here is the code I think the issue would be found in:

```
self.effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];
GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho(0, 480, 0, 320, -1024, 1024);
self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix = projectionMatrix;

self.player = [[SGGSprite alloc] initWithFile:@"Player.png" effect:self.effect];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check that the 'Player.png' image for your sprite has the correct case. iOS images are case sensitive on devices, but not the simulator. Hence, an image that might appear on your simulator might not be appearing correctly on your device.

Other than that, it could be a problem with the path to the file. So please ensure that you have set the correct path to your image file.